# Manual import of answers from third party forums. Good or bad?

Tags: discussion, answers

Many times, I share the links of questions(not just mine) on other forums like Reddit, Facebook study groups, etc.

And I get some really good answers from those sites, which deserve to be here. However, when I ask them to post the answer in the respective SE site, they are reluctant to do so (Not sure why).

So, in those cases, can I post those answers here (underneath the specific questions), citing the link of the original answer? Sometimes, it is multiple answers(for the same qn) which I feel are really good, and users here would benefit from them.

Is it okay or frowned upon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it is okay to me. If you want to share knowledge, why not? There are things to consider though:

- Reputation: Some people find it unfair if you reuse an answer of someone else and take credit for that. Making the answer a community wiki would solve that.
- License: Make sure the license of the platform you get that answer from allows redistributing it under the license of the SE sites. If not, you could violate copyright, etc. If there is no clear copyright notice or license statement, the author has to grant you rights to post it.

Comment: Is it really any different from quoting from external sources (books, articles, journals etc), quoting the relevant text passages and then providing a link back to the source where you can go to read the full thing? I'm sure I see answers referencing data from behind paywalls, so I would assume this is something similar.

Comment: I would agree to that, not so much different. @JonW